# error: passing 'const' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

THIS is academico.h

```
#ifndef ACADEMICO_H
#define ACADEMICO_H

#include "empleado.h"


class academico: public empleado
{
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &,academico &);

    public:
        academico();
        virtual void imprimir () const;
        virtual float neto () const;
        string nivel10() ;

    private:
        char NivelE;
        int Ptj;


};
```

empleado constructor import: string nombre,string codigo,int edad[3] and float SalarioB

```
academico::academico() : empleado()
{
    NivelE = ' ';
    Ptj = 0;
}
```

In this part I take all the variables, it works really well, I've proved it before

```
istream &operator >>(istream &op, academico &a)
{
    cout << "\nIngrese el codigo del empleado: ";
    op >> a.codigo;
    cout << "\nIngrese el nombre del empleado: ";
    op >> a.nombre;

    do
    {
        cout << "\nIngrese el anio de nacimiento (mayor 1900): ";
        op >> a.edad[2];
    }while(a.edad[2]<1900);

    do
    {
        cout << "\nIngrese el mes de nacimiento (1-12): ";
        op >> a.edad[1];
    }while(a.edad[1]<1 || a.edad[1]>12);
    if(a.edad[1] == 2)
    {

        if(bisiesto(a.edad[2]))
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "\nIngrese el dia de nacimiento (1-29): "; 
                op>>a.edad[0];
            }while(a.edad[0] < 1 || a.edad[0] > 29);
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "\nIngrese el dia de nacimiento (1-28): "; 
                op>>a.edad[0];
            }while(a.edad[0] < 1 || a.edad[0] > 28);     
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "\nIngrese el dia de nacimiento (1-31): ";
            op >> a.edad[0];    
        }while(a.edad[0]<1 || a.edad[0]>dias[a.edad[1]]);
    }

    do
    {
        cout << "\nIngrese el salario basico: ";
        op >> a.salarioB;    
    }while(a.salarioB<0); 


    do
    {
        cout << "Ingrese su nivel de estudio(Mayuscula): ";
        op >> a.NivelE;

    } while (a.NivelE != 'T' && a.NivelE != 'P' && a.NivelE != 'E' && a.NivelE != 'M' && a.NivelE != 'D' );

    do
    {
        cout << "Cual es su puntaje de investigacion: ";
        op >> a.Ptj;

    }while(a.Ptj<0);

 }
```

this part have the error, but idk what is the problem

```
string nivel10()
{
    return "arroba";
}


void academico::imprimir() const
{
    cout << nivel10();
    cout << "\nNombre: " << nombre;
    cout << "\nCodigo: " << codigo;
    cout << "\nFecha nacimiento: " << edad[0] << " De "  << meses1[edad[1]] << " Año " << edad [2];
    cout << "\nSalario Basico: " << salarioB;
    cout << "\npuntaje: " << Ptj;
}

#endif /* ACADEMICO_H */
```

note: Empleado.h only past parameters to constructor of academico.h

the objective of this code is to ask data to a worker to calculate their salary and show it, but no matter the modifications made to the method "Level10", always fails

main file

```
#include "academico.h"



using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    academico c;

    cin >> c;

    c.imprimir();

    return 0;
}
```

error: passing 'const academico' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Comment: `nivel10();` is not a `const` class method. `imprimir()` is a `const` class method. `const` class methods can only call other `const` class methods. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i pass method to const and this is the new erro:

In file included from main.cpp:16:0:
academico.h:116:18: error: non-member function 'std::string nivel10()' cannot have cv-qualifier
 string nivel10() const

Comment: "I passed method to const" does not make any sense to me, and I'm afraid that my mind-ray beam machine is not working, so I have no idea what actual changes were made, so I can't make any more suggestions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I finally solved the problem thank you very much